# Is there a function to store results of a for loop as variables?

Tags: python, arrays, variables, printing, python-3.8

I have a function defined that produces an array counting the number of 1's, 2's, etc. in a separate array. 
Using this loop (x y and z are test cases)

```
List=[x,y,z]
for file in List:
    pixel_count(file)
```

I want to take pre-established arrays and count the number of 1s, 2s etc in each separate array. currently pixel count has a print at the end which gives the correct output, but i want to store those in variables to manipulate later. Is there a way to do this?

Currently using i am using the below to generate dummy arrays.

```
x = [randint(1, 255) for j in range(20000)]
y = [randint(1, 255) for j in range(20000)]
z = [randint(1, 255) for j in range(20000)]
```

The output is an array "result" for x, y and z, which is a 255 character array where positions 0-3 looks like [73,79,84,72]. I want to store the results as something like resultx, resulty, resultz. Eventually x, y and z will be image names, so i want to keep it flexible.

Comment: there sure is. but what language are you using? Add it to your question as a tag

Comment: I think it would be better to give an example of a possible array, it doesn't have to be the whole thing, something small, and your expected output.  That way people can copy and paste that array to be able to come up with a solution.  It is hard to tell what you are after here.

Comment: Updated with more info

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.bincount(your_array)` which will return a list of 4 elements where the index [0] will have the total number of occurences of 0, and so on. You can find the documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html.